# Can't insert into temp table when in read only mode MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I am unable to insert into temp table's in MySQL 5.6 if it's in read only mode & with log_bin on.  It works fine if log_bin is off.  I can see there is old bug report's for 5.5 but this has said to be fixed for 5.6. I am unable to find anyone else with this problem for 5.6 so I'm thinking I must have something configured wrong.

What is the correct way to be able to insert into a temp table when server is in read only mode (as it's a slave) and have log_bin on?

To reproduce (as you can see from the grants, this user is not a super user)

```
add
vi /etc/my.cnf

log_bin=mysql-bin

log_slave_updates=1

mysql -utest_user -p singapore

Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.

Your MySQL connection id is 23

Server version: 5.6.27 MySQL Community Server (GPL)


Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.


Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its

affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective

owners.


Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.


mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'test_user'@'----';


Grants for test_user@----                                                                

GRANT CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES ON *.* TO 'test_user'@'----' IDENTIFIED BY 
PASSWORD '----' 

 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test_user`.* TO 'test_user'@'----'                              


mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table2 AS (SELECT * FROM view limit 1);


Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


mysql> insert into table2 (session, date) value ('test', now());

ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option 
so it cannot execute this statement


mysql> exit
```

Bye

Comment: Please cite the resolved bug you found. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62008 is the same issue, and does not appear resolved; it also provides a workaround, setting `binlog_format=ROW`, which makes sense in one sense, since in row-based logging, temp tables are not written to the binlog.